# Regular expression to check number greater than 100

Tags: java, regex

I want to construct a Regular Expression in Java that allows a number that is greater than 100. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Can't you just parse the number (I assume which is in string format
) into an int and then compare?. Regex seems to be *too much* here

Comment: why are you SHOUTING?

Answer (score 11):

```
^(?!(?:\d{1,2}|100)$)[0-9]\d+$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/549

Comment: if you could explain your great answer, it would be awesome

Comment: @KickButtowski it just says that `first digit should be from 1 to 9,then there should be one digit from 0 to 9 and then there should be one or more digits.` .The lookahead just makes sure `100` is not matched.

Comment: Hello @AhmedAbdelhameed I am not getting the `|[2-9]` part and why does substituting it with `|[1-9]` messes everything up i.e. includes the 100 again?

Comment: @vks Yeah, that seems to work. I believe the `[0-9]` is redundant though.

Comment: @motaha Sorry, I accidentally deleted my comment before I saw your question. Anyway, the pattern in the comment was [`^(?:1(?!00$)|[2-9])\d{2,}+$`](https://regex101.com/r/17NT0f/1) which means `A "1" that is not followed by "00" OR a digit between 2 and 9 followed by two or more digits`. Using `|[1-9]` negates the effect of the first part of the pattern _by explicitly allowing `100`_. Hope it's clear now. You can also use vks's updated pattern above.. it'll be even shorter if you remove the `[0-9]` which I still believe is redundant xD

Comment: @motaha do upvote if you find this helpful :)